# Formal American English form of 'generalization of the generalized'

Tags: writing

I have a question regarding formal American English writing. I constructed a method which is a generalization of the generalized finite element method (GFEM). The fact that it's a generalization is an important message I want to give in the title of my article, but obviously, 'generalization of the generalized finite element method' sounds ridiculous. I can however, not seem to find any synonym for 'generalization'.

My question is, how do I express this in formal American English writing?

Comment: Can you explain how a second generalisation is possible after the first one? There must have been an incompleteness in some sense. Eg 'generalise to cover _all_ English nouns' can be followed by 'generalise to cover all nouns in all languages' ...

Comment: The second generalization could expand the range of applicability (covering more systems), or remove some limitations of the generalized model.

Comment: @aeismail. Of course, but what alternative do you suggest?

Comment: Ridiculous though the repetition may sound, there's one precedent for such a title: *The Incoherence of the Incoherence* (*Tahafut al-tahafut*), Averroes' refutation of *The Incoherence of the Philosophers*.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth. Indeed, but I think the title is no place to explain what the former method was lacking or what the new generalization entails :(.

Comment: Indeed, but you have plenty of space to expand upon these things after the title. It would help to know at least some of the specifics of the generalisation, rather than have to guess (as aeismail has valiantly done). I'd say that, as it stands, your question is too broad for any answer better than Peter's.

Comment: What about `An extension of the Generalized Finite Element Method` or `An enhancement of the Generalized Finite Element Method`. Which one is more formal and more pervasive/strident?

Answer (score 1):

You could make the title

> A Further Generalization of the Generalized Finite Element Method.

That way, at least you acknowledge that you're generalizing a generalization.

Comment: Hmmm.....indeed sounds better.....But I wonder if there are even better alternatives...